# Finding time complexity Big-Θ of this recursive formula involving floor function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, floor

I am trying to find the time complexity (Big-Θ) of this algorithm:

```
Recursion(n):
   while n > 1:
      n = floor(n/2)
      Recursion(n)
```

I have found an upper bound of O(n) by considering the worst case which is when n is a power of 2.

However, I am having trouble finding a lower bound (Big-Ω) for this. My intuition is that this is Ω(n) as well, but I am not sure how to show this with the floor function in the way.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

EDIT: the main thing I'm not convinced of is that T(n/2) is equivalent to T(floor(n/2)). How would one prove this for this algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`floor` function performs its operation in constant time, `O(1)`. Therefore you can ignore it/see it as a constant. Let's analyze the time complexity of the algorithm below:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + 1 (floor operation)
T(n/2) = T(n/4) + 1
...
T(2) = T(1) + 1    --> T(1) = constant

T(n) = T(n/4) + 2
T(n) = T(n/8) + 3
...
T(n) = T(n/2^k) + k    2^k = n therefore k=log(n)
T(n) = T(1) + log(n)
T(n) = log(n)
```

We can conclude that `T(n)` ∈ `θ(log(n))`.

Comment: Wouldn't T(n) = T(n/2) + 1 + T(n/4) + 1 + T(n/8) + ...?

Comment: No, why do you think that way? Could you show your calculations? Notice that we divide the ```n``` by 2 each time and get to the very depth. Number of operations must be ```log(n)``` at most.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't really understand why T(n) = T(n/2) + 1 is true. In particular, I'm not convinced that T(floor(n/2)) is equivalent to T(n/2)

Comment: ```T(floor(n/2)) ≈ T(n/2)```, we can make this approximation for the sake of simplicity. Because floor(n/2) is either n/2, or n/2 - fraction. These are typical approximations made to do calculations simpler.

Comment: I thought T(n) would call T(floor(n/2)), and then in the next iteration of the while loop call T(floor(floor(n/2)/2)), and then in the next iteration of the while loop call T(floor(floor(floor(n/2)/2)/2)) and so on, so wouldn't T(n) be the sum of all of these?

Comment: You are right in your last comment. It is exactly what happens, if you make the calculations you'll see that number of operations will be approximately ```log(n)```.

Comment: ```T(n/2) is equivalent to T(floor(n/2))``` This statement is wrong.

Comment: ```T(floor(n/2)) ≈ T(n/2)``` This statement is correct

Comment: Disprove the first statement by example:  Let ```n``` be 3. Then T(3/2) = T(1.5) = 2 operations (floor and T(1)). But T(floor(3/2)) = T(1) = 1 operation.

Comment: Such approximations are made in time complexity analysis. Because we are talking about huge input sizes. Millions, billions etc. In that sense ```T(floor(n/2)) ≈ T(n/2)```